# Unable to plot linear regression scatter plot and predicting line

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression

I have tried lot of methods and went through many questions that are already answered over here but in vain. None of it could solve my problem. So please if you can't solve this problem at least don't mark it as 'duplicate' because am desparately looking forward to make my model work and am stuck at this stupid syntactical error.

So, my query is pretty simple, I have a data frame that consists of 2 columns 1st is 'sqft_living' and the second is 'price'. So, I have used linear regression to predict price based on its sqft area. I want to visualize this, as scatter plot followed by a best fit line. However, am getting this error: 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
I have already converted the dataframe into series and corrected dimensions as well still am getting this error.
Please provide me with solution code along with exploitation.
Any help will be highly appreciated as I am stuck with this and can't complete my assignment.
below is the exact code and error i am getting.

`````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To visualize
import pandas as pd  # To read data
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = poly1_data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # values converts it into a numpy array
Y = poly1_data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # -1 means that calculate the dimension of rows, but have 1 column
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)  # make predictions
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='red')
plt.show()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-96227c9411b1> in <module>
      9 linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression
     10 Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)  # make predictions
---> 11 plt.scatter(X, Y)
     12 plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='red')
     13 plt.show()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, data, **kwargs)
   2860         vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths,
   2861         verts=verts, edgecolors=edgecolors, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2862         is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2863     sci(__ret)
   2864     return __ret

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4170             edgecolors = 'face'
   4171 
-> 4172         self._process_unit_info(xdata=x, ydata=y, kwargs=kwargs)
   4173         x = self.convert_xunits(x)
   4174         y = self.convert_yunits(y)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_unit_info(self, xdata, ydata, kwargs)
   2133             return kwargs
   2134 
-> 2135         kwargs = _process_single_axis(xdata, self.xaxis, 'xunits', kwargs)
   2136         kwargs = _process_single_axis(ydata, self.yaxis, 'yunits', kwargs)
   2137         return kwargs

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_single_axis(data, axis, unit_name, kwargs)
   2116                 # We only need to update if there is nothing set yet.
   2117                 if not axis.have_units():
-> 2118                     axis.update_units(data)
   2119 
   2120             # Check for units in the kwargs, and if present update axis

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in update_units(self, data)
   1471         neednew = self.converter != converter
   1472         self.converter = converter
-> 1473         default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
   1474         if default is not None and self.units is None:
   1475             self.set_units(default)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py in default_units(data, axis)
    101         # default_units->axis_info->convert
    102         if axis.units is None:
--> 103             axis.set_units(UnitData(data))
    104         else:
    105             axis.units.update(data)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py in __init__(self, data)
    167         self._counter = itertools.count()
    168         if data is not None:
--> 169             self.update(data)
    170 
    171     def update(self, data):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py in update(self, data)
    184         data = np.atleast_1d(np.array(data, dtype=object))
    185 
--> 186         for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data):
    187             if not isinstance(val, (str, bytes)):
    188                 raise TypeError("{val!r} is not a string".format(val=val))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

````[I am getting this image without any scatter plot and best fit line][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jccu.png
`````

Comment: Tell us about `X` and `Y`.  `shape`, `dtype`?

Comment: `plt.plot(X.squeeze(), Y_pred.squeeze(), color='red')` might work . . .

Comment: `scatter` doesn't have a problem with (n,1) data.  There must be some dtype or values in `X` or `Y` that are giving problems.  But what would work for the `fit` but not the `scatter` is a puzzle.

Comment: @hpaulj  here is the type and shape details
````print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
print(type(X))
print(type(Y))
````

(9761, 1)
(9761, 1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Looking a instructions like this: https://usermanual.wiki/Pdf/week03polynomialregressionassignmentinstructions.963954978.pdf, makes me wonder whether you are extracting the right columns from the dataframe.  The full `king-county` data set has many columns, the first is 'id', a string.

Comment: I asked for `dtype`, not `type`!  Make sure you understand the difference before you do more work with `numpy`.

Comment: @cs95 I tried your suggestion but it is still showing the same error

Comment: @hpaulj I checked it out and found that 'dtype' of both X and Y is 'Object'.
I have created another dataframe called 'poly1_data' which comprises of two columns 'sqft_living' and 'price' respectively at column index 0 and 1.

Comment: Look at some of the values in those arrays.  Are they numbers?  Can you convert them to a numeric dtype?  `X.astype(float)`

Comment: @hpaulj thanks a ton!!! am finally feeling relieved. It worked!!! 
I changed the data type to float and it worked. Thanks a lot!